# How do I sent data to another window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to send form data to a new window. I decided to use window.postMessage and addEventListener. A new window is opened, but addEventListener sees nothing.
This is the first component I'm sending data from:

```
async function submit(...props) {
    let data = props[0]

    if(status.current === "preview"){
        const handleLoad = () => {
            sendDataToTab(data);
            tab.current.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
        };
        openNewTab()
        tab.current.onload = () => {
            handleLoad()
        }
    }
}

const openNewTab = () => {
    if (tab.current === null || tab.current.closed) {
        tab.current = window.open(`${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/employer/add-offer/preview`, '_blank');
    } else {
        tab.current.focus();
    }
}

const sendDataToTab = (data) => {
    if (tab.current === null || tab.current.closed) {
      console.log('No tab is currently open!');
    } else {
        tab.current.postMessage(JSON.stringify(data), `${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}`);
    }
}
```

and second component:

```
const onMessageReceived = (event) => {
    console.log(`Received message from parent window: ${event.data}`);
};
          
const addMessageListener = () => {
    window.addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived);
};
  
useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
        const receiveMessage = (event) => {
            if (event.origin === `${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}`) {
                addMessageListener();
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: What are `tab` and `tab.current` here?

Comment: @Wyck `const tab = useRef(null)`

Answer (score 0):

the issue is, that you are receiving the first message. but instead of printing the result, you are trying to add another event listener.
and this again and again. starting with the second message you would get console.logs..

try this instead:

```js
const onMessageReceived = (event) => {
    console.log(`Received message from parent window: ${event.data}`);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
        // will be called for every incoming msg
        const receiveMessage = (event) => {
            console.log('unfiltered incoming msg from', event.origin);

            if (event.origin === `${env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}`) {
                onMessageReceived(event);
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: I still have the problem that `receiveMessage` is not called :(

Comment: add some console logs. is the useEffect being called? is the window check fine? maybe its not even registered..

Comment: maybe you register the callback too late, the event is already gone. maybe you need to do it outside of the react thingy.. to be "fast enough"?

Comment: or is it not called even if you do send multiple messages?

Comment: useEffect is fine, window also is, but window.addEventListener does nothing

Comment: yeah, you're right. When I do outside of this component, addEventListener works